# Mapping SAML identity to user in my own database in PHP

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

Currently I have a PHP (Laravel) application which has it's own user management and authentication.I'm trying to implement single sign on with ADFS (Active Directory Federated Services).

I set up a directory in Azure and I added a new "Application" to it. Azure provides examples on how to authenticate using javascript, Android and iOS so I downloaded the sample javascript code and everything worked. The client/browser obtains an access token, but how do I identify the user on my backend (PHP) code?

I need to take the user's AD identity and map it to a local user in my own database, and then issue a new access token based on that user in my own app so I can use all my existing authorization logic.

However, I'm not sure the best way to achieve this. My current idea is to take the access token obtained from javascript in the browser, pass it to the backend and then the backend server will call a Microsoft API (eg https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/) to obtain a unique ID for the user which I can then map to my own database and issue my own access token. Is this a recommended approach? What other alternatives exist?

Answer (score 0):

When a user authenticates to an application through Azure AD using the SAML 2.0 protocol, Azure AD sends a token to the application (via an HTTP POST). And then, the application validates and uses the token to log the user in instead of prompting for a username and password. These SAML tokens contain pieces of information about the user known as claims.

A claim is information that an identity provider states about a user inside the token they issue for that user. In SAML token, this data is typically contained in the SAML Attribute Statement. The user’s unique ID is typically represented in the SAML Subject also called as Name Identifier.

By default, Azure AD issues a [SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0) token to your application that contains a NameIdentifier claim with a value of the user’s username (also known as the user principal name) in Azure AD, which can uniquely identify the user. The SAML token also contains additional claims containing the user’s email address, first name, and last name.

To view or edit the claims issued in the SAML token to the application, open the application in Azure portal. Then open the User Attributes & Claims section.

[image]

If the SAML request contains the element NameIDPolicy with a specific format, then Azure AD will honor the format in the request.

If the SAML request doesn't contain an element for NameIDPolicy, then Azure AD will issue the NameID with the format you specify. If no format is specified Azure AD will use the default source format associated with the claim source selected.

[image]

You can read more about claim mapping here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping#table-3-valid-id-values-per-source

In a nutshell you can send the SAML token to your backend app and use the SAML response to extract NameIdentifier and map it to your database.

Hope it helps.